# How can export from default-exporting module in reacjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I resolve this error, Should not import the named export 'destinations' (imported as 'destinations') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)
Here the code snippet

```
import React from 'react'


import { useState } from 'react'


import {destinations} from '../assets/space-tourism-website-main/starter-code/data.json'


const Destinations = () => {

    const [planets] = useState(destinations)

    console.log(planets)

  return (

    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Destinations
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot destructure a `.json` file, at least not with your current config. What you need to do is import the entire `JSON` and use the properties as is.
Like so

```
import React from 'react'

import { useState } from 'react'


import dataJson from '../assets/space-tourism-website-main/starter-code/data.json'


const Destinations = () => {

    const [planets] = useState(dataJson.destinations)

    console.log(planets)

  return (

    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Destinations
```

Comment: Thanks. My images inside the data are in strings, how do get them back as images